# Remove plus sign from beginning and replace whitespaces of number

Tags: android, regex, variables, tasker

I need edit the string variable in Tasker "Variable Search Replace" but dont recognize the special characters.

I need edit below string

```
+70 888 777 1 1 3
to;
70888777113
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following to match (Easy approach):

```
\D               //(any non digit)
```

And replace with `''` (empty string)

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kA9uJ9/5)

**Code:**

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

**Edit:** If your string is a part of another string use the following:

```
(?<=\d)\s+(?=\d)|\+(?=\d)
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kA9uJ9/6)

Explanation:

- `(?<=\d)\\s+(?=\d)` All white spaces surrounded by digits
- `\+(?=\d)` plus sign in the beginning of digits

Comment: Please explain downvotes? So that I could improve the answer?

Comment: I type \D to Search section in Tasker Variable Search Replace module. And it is work. now directly return 70888777113 to me.

Comment: @BlackWhite yes it will.. :)

Answer (score 1):

if `String tmp = "+70 888 777 1 1 3";`

then

```
   tmp = tmp.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

will remove all the white space from `tmp`, and

```
if (tmp.startWith("+")) {
    tmp = tmp.substring(1, tmp.length());
}
```

will remove the `+`

Answer (score 1):

You may replace all white spaces from string by using following :

```
 $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

Comment: This is not PHP and question is not for replacing just spaces!

Answer (score 0):

try this code it worked fine in java

```
String str = "+1234567";
if(str.substring(0, 0).equals("+")){
   // assign value string value expect first character 
   str = str.substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code
String tmp = "+70 888 777 1 1 3";
tmp replaceAll("[^0-9]+","");